# Python regex inconsistent output between groups() and group()

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am doing a little test to grab backslash (`\`) using Python regex and what I found is a bit strange.

```
import re
stringing = "\\"
pattern = re.compile(r'(\\)')
search = pattern.search(string)
print search.group()
```

The output is shown below, which is as expected

```
\
```

However, when I use `.groups() as,`

```
print search.groups()
```

I get

```
('\\',)
```

Which is clearly wrong. Not sure what is happening.

[image]

Comment: try `search.group()` alone without print. It will give you `'\\'` not a backslash.

Comment: Yes it does. Why is that though? Isn't it supposed to give only one `\\`

Comment: i think it's because of the ide you're running.

Comment: try this `for i in re.search(r'(\\)', s).groups(): print i`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am running in a Python interpreter opened inside a linux terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** `\` is the `str` representation of the backslash character and `'\\'` is the `repr` representation of the backslash character.

In this case, `search.group` returns a string. The actual string representation of `\` is `\` only. But, when you print a tuple, it internally calls the `repr` on all the objects in it. The result of `repr` on `\` is `'\\'`.

You can check that like this

```
print repr(search.group()), str(search.group())
# '\\' \
```